# Should the tags *word-classes* and *parts-of-speech* be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I don't know of any definition where they are not synonyms and many relevant questions use both.

Comment: I agree. I can't see any reason not to class them as synonyms.

Comment: I would regard them as synonymous as well.